# How to add facebook pixel and conversion code to shopware 5

Tags: php, facebook, smarty, e-commerce, shopware

I am using Shopware 5.1.2. I am new to this templating system.

I am trying to add FB pixcel code to the header file.
So I created fb.tpl under `/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/index`  folder

I was appending it to modernizr block:

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/index/fb.tpl'}

{block name="frontend_index_header_javascript_modernizr_lib" append}
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
{/block}
```

I also tried adding the fb.tpl to the specific theme folder.

And cleared cache.
Still the FB code is not visible in the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your file to **Responsive** (or your active theme) theme & rename it as **header.tpl** like:

```
/themes/Frontend/Responsive/frontend/index/header.tpl
```

Modify file content like below:

```
{extends file='parent:frontend/index/header.tpl'}

{block name="frontend_index_header_javascript_tracking" append}
{literal}
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->

<!-- YOUR Facebook Pixel Code HERE -->

<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
{/literal}
{/block}
```

From Backend menu perform:

```
Configuration > Theme Manager > Select Active Theme > Compile Theme
```

Reload frontend page. It should work!

Comment: I done exactly. When I clear cache, I see website with error. <br> We have been notified and back again. <br>  So I rolled back

Comment: Did you place {literal} tag inside {block} as in my answer ?

Comment: Hi Gins, Sorry for late reply. Yes, I missed {literal} code. It works fine now. Thanks

Comment: Another question: Sorry for not asking separately. How to get the current page is thankyou page and order value

Comment: I didn't get your last question clearly. Check $Basket in /themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/checkout/finish.tpl